# why does pthread_cond_signal cause deadlock

Tags: c++, c, pthreads, mutex, condition-variable

I am new to conditional variables and get deadlock if not using `pthread_cond_broadcast()`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t m_mut = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cv = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

bool ready = false;

void* print_id (void *ptr )
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m_mut);
    while (!ready) pthread_cond_wait(&cv, &m_mut);
    int id = *((int*) ptr);
    std::cout << "thread " << id  << '\n';
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m_mut);
    pthread_exit(0);
    return NULL;
}
```

condition is changed here!

```
void go() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m_mut);
    ready = true;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m_mut);
    pthread_cond_signal(&cv);
}
```

It can work if I change the last line of `go()` to `pthread_cond_broadcast(&cv);`

```
int main ()
{
    pthread_t threads[10];

    // spawn 10 threads:
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, print_id, (void *) new int(i));

    go();

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&m_mut);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&cv);

    return 0;
}
```

The expected answer (arbitrary order) is

```
thread 0

....

thread 9
```

However, on my machine (ubuntu), it prints nothing.
Could anyone tell me the reason? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. _signal wakes up an arbitrary thread on the waiting list. Do I miss anything?

Comment: _"However ... it prints nothing."_  Really?  At first glance I'm dubious.  Assuming stdout is line buffered (e.g., a terminal), I understand why the program might print anywhere from 1 to 10 lines of output, but not zero lines of output.  If some threads are faster than `main`, as it were, at least one of them will be signaled and thus produce output.  If some threads are slower than `main`, they'll find that `ready` is ready and also output a line each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the manual page (with my emphasis):

> `pthread_cond_signal` restarts one of the threads that are waiting on the condition variable `cond`. If no threads are waiting on `cond`, nothing happens. *If several threads are waiting on `cond`, exactly one is restarted, but it is not specified which.*
>
> `pthread_cond_broadcast` restarts all the threads that are waiting on the condition variable `cond`. Nothing happens if no threads are waiting on `cond`.

Each of your ten threads is waiting on the same condition. You only call `go()` once - that's from `main()`. This calls `pthread_cond_signal`, which will only signal *one* of the threads (an arbitrary one). All the others will still be waiting, and hence the `pthread_join` hangs as they won't terminate. When you switch it to `pthread_cond_broadcast`, *all* of the threads are triggered.

Comment: In my code, a thread must acquire a mutex before it can wait on the condition variable. I thought only one thread can wait on `cv`, am i right?

Comment: Yes. `pthread_cond_wait` requires the mutex is locked on entry and automatically unlocks it, relocking it on exit.

Comment: Hmm, I still do not understand why it prints nothing. Do the ten threads wait on the `cv`? If they do, why I cannot use _signal?

Comment: I can't tell you whether all ten threads wait on `cv`, because you haven't shown all the code, but I can only presume that's what's happening. If they all call `print_id` then yes they do. If so, `pthread_cond_signal` is not going to work as it is going to trigger one of the waiting threads at random, and you are only calling `go()` once, so only one will be triggered.

Comment: Actually yes, you've shown enough code to show that's absolutely the problem. I will amend my answer.